# htaccess redirect using RewriteCond and RewriteRule - complex url using regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to create a  301 redirect using htaccess.

Example :

Take this url (old): domain/page.html?pid=21&cid=730:pagetitle

redirect to (new): http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/pagetitle

i tried  this, but dont work :(

```
##([0-9]+)?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=21&cid=[0-9]{1,5}:(.*)
RewriteRule ^/page.html http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/%1? [NC,R=301]
```

the pagetitle and cid are dynamic and will change overtime.

ideally i want to take the old url and strip everything apart from pagetitle (domain/page.html?pid=2&cid=730:pagetitle) and than use this as query string for my redirect url....

thanks

UPDATE:

More example:

From:

http://www.domain.co.uk/page.html?pid=1&cid=25:helloworld

http://www.domain.co.uk/page.html?pid=1&cid=34:hellonew-world

http://www.domain.co.uk/page.html?pid=1&cid=21:1pagetitle

To:

http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/helloworld

http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/hellonew-world

http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/1pagetitle

note: section = pid 1

Results using Omega or mine rewrite rules gives a 404 page at moment.

i only need the last part of query string - cid (page title), pid not important.

Comment: can you expand on your URL examples, including query string? eg, if I understand correctly, are you asking how to redirect from: `http://www.example.com/page.html?pid=<pid>&cid=<cid>:<somepagetitle>` to: `http://www.example.com/page/section/<somepagetitle>?pid=<pid>&cid=<cid>` ? Multiple, complete, examples might make it easier to understand what you want. Multiple, complete, examples of what is currently happening (which you don't want) may also be helpful.

Comment: @will-palmer I have updated the question with more example, please have a look. thanks

Comment: @Will Palmer I have updated the question with more example, please have a look. thanks

Comment: So if you go to the URL `http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/helloworld`, do you get a 404?

Comment: @Jon Lin yes at moment i get 404 page

Answer (score 0):

To keep query string parameter(s), instead of `[NC,R=301]` use `[NC,R=301,QSA]`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cid=[0-9]{1,5}:(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/%1 [NC,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  your rule makes sense and works fine using rewrite tester but fails and  return a 404 page on the live site. I have updated the question with more example, please have a look. thanks

Comment: @TheDeveloper - Check your log files for reason of error 404, to find out what url has failed

Comment: odd nothing in the log..  `http://www.domain.co.uk/page.html?pid=1&cid=21:1pagetitle` is not rewritten or redirected in the address bar, it should `http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/1pagetitle`

Comment: thanks, just checked your update, still gives me 404. url rewrite does not seem to work, a basic RedirectMatch 301 kinda works. can the above be transformed in RedirectMatch 301?

Comment: @TheDeveloper - You would need to turn on `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` logging to learn what is going on... See documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think using {1,5} might be the problem in your version. That syntax may not be available.

But this version ought to work ok:

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}  ^pid=21&cid=[0-9]+:(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^page\.html      http://www.domain.co.uk/page/section/%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```